# Date Difference Pandas

Tags: pandas

Hello I am trying to do a simple date difference on a pandas df. Below is a sample of the DF i am working with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'id':277176, 'Date1':'3/22/2021', 'Date2':'4/22/2021'}
    ], index='id)

|     id | Date1    | Date2     |
|-------:|:----------|:----------|
| 277176 | 3/22/2021 | 4/22/2021 |
```

Below is the code i am using to calculate the date difference

```py
date1 = df['Date1']
date2 = df['Date2'] 

date1 = pd.to_datetime(date1)
date2 = pd.to_datetime(date2)

df['Date_diff'] = (date1-date2)
```

Below is the output i am getting which is not correct:

```
573    NaT 
Name: Date1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: It could be because it's negative?

Comment: I suspect you have some index alignment issues.  Use something like data1 = df.loc[573, 'Date1'] and data2 = df.loc[573,'Date2'], are both date1 and date2 not np.Nan?

Answer (score 0):

When I recreate your problem, I don't get any issues:

```
df['Datet1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datet1'])
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])

df['Date_diff'] = df['Datet1'] - df['Date2']

|     id | Datet1              | Date2               | Date_diff          |
|-------:|:--------------------|:--------------------|:-------------------|
| 277176 | 2021-03-22 00:00:00 | 2021-04-22 00:00:00 | -31 days +00:00:00 |
```

***Is it possible that you have multiple copies of `df` in which some of the dates are empty?***